# SwiftUI: provide for loop upper limit from other component

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, foreach, swiftui

My problem is the following, I have a product view where I load to the view the data, I need to add a rating display based on a star system.

Call:

```
     var rating = 4.22
     RatingView(rating)
```

Input: I have the rating in double format, and I provide to the RatingView this data.

Output: It's basically a floor function based on the number provided with the same number of stars
[image]

Problem: The problem is that I will always get an error no matter if I use a for or forEach loop.
I tried in the following ways:

```
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
            ForEach(Int(rating), id: \.self) { _ in
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 8, weight: .regular))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
```

with error: Cannot convert value of type '(*) -> some View' to expected argument type '(*) -> _'

or

```
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
        for index in 0..<Int(rating) {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 8, weight: .regular))
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
        }
```

with error: Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'

I really don't know how to change the loop so that it can display what is needed...

Comment: Did you try rounding it? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884722-round

Comment: The rounding isn't a problem as the conversion from double to int works pretty much the same. I was having errors iterating over an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` expects sequenced data or range, so you need something like the following (not taking into account how you round your rating)

```
ForEach(0..<Int(rating), id: \.self) { _ in
```